# How to post a WebGrid to a Controller using Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, webgrid

I want to post the full `WebGrid` from my view to my controller using ajax. In this `WebGrid` I display a table from a database and I want to provide, that the user of this webpage can update the columns (in the database).

My try so far:

#### Controller

```
public JsonResult UpdateTable(GridView model)
{
    // Update Model to db..
    string message = "Success";
    return Json(message, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

> The `GridView model` here has always 0 columns.

#### View/Script

WebGrid

```
<div id="tableGridDiv">
    @grid.GetHtml(
    tableStyle: "table", columns: cols)
</div>
```

Script

```
$('.save-user').on('click', function () {
    var grid = $("#tableGridDiv").find("table.grid").first();
    alert(grid.innerHTML);
    var jsonGrid = JSON.stringify(grid);
    //var jsonGrid = $.parseJSON(grid);
    alert(jsonGrid);
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/UpdateTable/',
        data: jsonGrid,
        datatype: JSON,
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json, charset=utf-8',
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
```

The outcome of `alert(jsonGrid)` is:

```
{
   "length":0,
   "prevObject":{
      "length":0,
      "prevObject":{
         "0":{
            "__browserLink_sourceMapping":[
               "~/Views/Home/ViewTable.cshtml",
               "div#tableGridDiv",
               4717,
               104,
               23
            ]
         },
         "length":1,
         "context":{
            "location":{
               "href":"http://localhost:56452/Home/ViewTable?View=0",
               "ancestorOrigins":{

               },
               "origin":"http://localhost:56452",
               "protocol":"http:",
               "host":"localhost:56452",
               "hostname":"localhost",
               "port":"56452",
               "pathname":"/Home/ViewTable",
               "search":"?View=0",
               "hash":""
            },
            "_html5shiv":1,
            "jQuery110201336937122154982":1
         },
         "selector":"#tableGridDiv"
      },
      "context":{
         "location":{
            "href":"http://localhost:56452/Home/ViewTable?View=0",
            "ancestorOrigins":{

            },
            "origin":"http://localhost:56452",
            "protocol":"http:",
            "host":"localhost:56452",
            "hostname":"localhost",
            "port":"56452",
            "pathname":"/Home/ViewTable",
            "search":"?View=0",
            "hash":""
         },
         "_html5shiv":1,
         "jQuery110201336937122154982":1
      },
      "selector":"#tableGridDiv table.grid"
   },
   "context":{
      "location":{
         "href":"http://localhost:56452/Home/ViewTable?View=0",
         "ancestorOrigins":{

         },
         "origin":"http://localhost:56452",
         "protocol":"http:",
         "host":"localhost:56452",
         "hostname":"localhost",
         "port":"56452",
         "pathname":"/Home/ViewTable",
         "search":"?View=0",
         "hash":""
      },
      "_html5shiv":1,
      "jQuery110201336937122154982":1
   }
}
```

I can't see columns or anything like that in here, so I guess I need something different?

Comment: Well, does the structure of the JSON in `jsonGrid` match the structure of the C# `GridView` object? Somehow I doubt it. If they don't match, then MVC will not be able to serialise your data into the gridview object.

Comment: @ADyson exactly, they don't match. I will add it to my question

Comment: IMO I doubt you want to accept a `GridView` object as the input in MVC. A gridview is a GUI display element. What you're really trying to update is the _data_ behind the gridview. So what you want is to get the data items out of the HTML, into a JavaScript object, which you can serialise to JSON. Your MVC controller would then accept an object which maps to the same structure, which you can use to update the database. It would make some sense if that object had a structure similar to your database tables, then it's easy to map from the object to that. Forget about grids, this is about raw data

Comment: @ADyson oh thanks a lot, can I use `DataTable`, or shall I use `List` as parameter?

Comment: @ADyson either `DataTable` or `List<dynamic>` are `null`. What do I need to change in my script?

Comment: Did you try simply `dynamic`. The JSON you're passing in looks like an object, not a list.

Comment: @ADyson yeah this gives me an object, how do I get the info out of this object now? :/

Comment: Well, for example, `model.length` would give you the length property. Just like any object, really. Which bits of the data are you actually interested in?

Comment: @ADyson I can't even see where I should get out the data from that JSON. I think there is no information provided about the columns of the grid.

Comment: @ADyson btw, I don't know the columns, they are dynamic. So i can't really get the info from the model?

Comment: If you don't know what the columns are, how exactly do you propose to save them to a database?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177080/discussion-between-david-walser-and-adyson).

Comment: P.S. In your JS you serialised the HTML element representing the grid. Like I said before, you need to actually extract the individual data items from each cell in the table. Maybe this particular plugin provides ready-made JS method to do that, rather than having to loop the individual cell elements, I don't know, you can check the documentation perhaps. I don't know if it provides a JS interface.

Comment: damn it, I need the whole table, because I don't just need "edit", I also need Insert and delete

Comment: if you're inserting a row you should be using a form and input fields, so it should be easy to capture those specific fields. Same for any updates, really. Again, still no need to try and export data from the table cells.

Comment: @ADyson yeah I know, but with forms and inputs I need to create own filtering and own paging :/

Comment: really, why? It sounds unlikely to me. Why would having an input form require you to write your own paging mechanism? The two things should be entirely unrelated? Once you've input the new or updated data and saved it to the database, you would simply cause the grid to refresh itself from the datasource. Then it can set the pages etc as it pleases.

Comment: lets go back to chat @ADyson